# Rename a file in assets/javascript Rails 3.2 in .js OpenShift

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, openshift, assets

I have the following question:
I'm programming a Rails app (Rails 3.2) and I'm using OpenShift as hosting.
Usually , when I finish a change on my project I upload everythings.
I see this strange thing:

if I rename a file in `assets/javascript` from the `.js.coffee` extension to `.js` , the OpenShift Gear give me the following problem

[image]

I really don't understand what is the problem. Is not possible in Rails , to edit the extension from `.js.coffee` to `.js`?
Obviously I'm in the Production mode.

Answer (score 0):

Searching in internet i find the solution of my  problem:

SOLUTION:

It is most probably because rails auto-generated an empty coffescript file for you as part of you generating a controller in you project. You also probably renamed the coffescript to a .js

In the empty js file you'll find auto-generated comments for coffescript which starts with # instead of // used by javascript. Just remove all comments and you're good to go.